# InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression for groupby

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I'm implementing an asp.net core project. I wrote a query like below in my code,

```
var RegisteredReqStatus = (from t1 in _context.Apiapplicant
                                       join t2 in _context.ApiApplicantHistory on t1.Id equals t2.ApiApplicantId
                                       join t3 in _context.EntityType on t2.LastReqStatus equals t3.Id
                                       where t1.IsDeleted.Equals(false) && t1.LastRequestStatus == t2.Id
                                       group t2 by t2.LastReqStatus into ApiAppGp
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           lastReqName = ApiAppGp.FirstOrDefault().LastReqStatusNavigation.Name,
                                           ReqCount = ApiAppGp.Count()
                                       }).ToList();
```

but after running my project, it shows me an error like below:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
>   '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: (a.lastReqStatus),
>   ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType:
>   ApiApplicantHistory ValueBufferExpression:
>   (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember) IsNullable: False
>   ) )
>   .FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

And here is my data models:

```
public partial class ApiApplicantHistory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? SentType { get; set; }
        public int? Reason { get; set; }
        public int? LastReqStatus { get; set; }


        public virtual Apiapplicant ApiApp { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType LastReqStatusNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType SentTypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType ReasonNavigation { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class EntityType
    {
        public EntityType()
        {
ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();            ApiApplicantHistorySentTypeNavigation = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
            ApiApplicantHistoryReasonNavigation = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EntityKey { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation { get; set; }        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiAppHistorySentTypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiAppHistoryReasonNavigation { get; set; }

    }
}

public partial class Apiapplicant
    {
        public Apiapplicant()
        {
            ApiApplicantHistory = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public int? LastRequestStatus { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiApplicantHistory { get; set; }
    }
```

I appreciate if anyone can suggest me a solution.

Comment: How about this? "Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()"

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Which bit didn't understand of the statement "Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()"?

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem in my query. It seems correct to me

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean it is correct. Entity Framework has to translate C# LINQ into SQL statement calls. Your code could not be translated. The error tells you there is something wrong with the `.FirstOrDefault()`. You must either rewrite the query so that it can be translated or bring the data into memory so that you can run your standard C# query against it. Does that help?

Comment: No because if i don't use firstOrDefault then I can not get any attribute from ApiAppGp.

Comment: No-one said you had to remove the `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this solves it:

```
var RegisteredReqStatus =
(
    from t1 in _context.Apiapplicant
    join t2 in _context.ApiApplicantHistory on new { X = t1.Id, Y = t1.LastRequestStatus } equals new { X = t2.ApiApplicantId, Y = t2.Id }
    join t3 in _context.EntityType on t2.LastReqStatus equals t3.Id
    where !t1.IsDeleted
    group t2 by t2.LastReqStatus into ApiAppGp
    from x in ApiAppGp.Take(1)
    select new
    {
        lastReqName = x.LastReqStatusNavigation.Name,
        ReqCount = ApiAppGp.Count()
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Now for the line "join t2 in _context.ApiApplicantHistory ...." it shows me an error like the following: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to join.

Comment: Could you please post your object model?